# How to access static variable from Dialog header file in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

CDialogI have `static int mStatus;` in `CDialogDlg.h`. I like to access that static variable from another `cpp file`, for example `test.cpp`. Normally is we access static variable as `CDialogDlg::mStatus = 1.` But when I include `CDialogDlg.h` into `test.h`, I got two compilation errors as

```
 Error 1: error C2504: 'CDialogEx' : base class undefined

 Error 2: error C2065: 'IDD_CDialog_DIALOG' : undeclared identifier
```

Why I can't include `CDialogDlg.h` into `test.h`.
I am not very familiar with MFC. Thanks.

Comment: Why including your dialog into your `test.h` ? Simply include your dialog in your include header or main.cpp before including your `test.h`.

Comment: @Blacktempel; Because I want to access (MyDlg::mStatus = 1) in test.cpp. This is MFC application and don't have main.cpp.

Comment: With your main.cpp is meant your CDialogDlg.cpp I thought you could imagine that.

Comment: @Blacktempel; Sorry I have edited. Not MyDlg.h, it is CDialogDlg.h. CDialogDlg.h is already included into main.cpp (as you said). But my problem is how to  use static variable CDialogDlg::mStatus in my test.cpp. To access CDialogDlg::mStatus, I have to include CDialogDlg.h into test.cpp. Then I got these errors. Thanks

Comment: Did you include `#include <afxdialogex.h>` ?

Comment: `error C2065: 'IDD_CDialog_DIALOG' : undeclared identifier` is because resource.h is not #include-d. Usually the resource `#define`-s are in `resource.h` which is created in the same directory as the project file.

Comment: The header `resource.h` is included by default. I don't think anyone would delete this.

Comment: Thanks  Blacktempel and  yasouser, after including #include <afxdialogex.h> and #include "resource.h". Now it works. Many thanks.

Comment: @batuman I'll post that as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the `#include "resource.h"` is usually included by default in your header file `CMyNameApp.h` it should have been `#include <afxdialogex.h>`. Even though you could have deleted `#include "resource.h"` from the header, so you would have to include it again.

```
#include "resource.h"
#include <afxdialogex.h>
```

Should solve your whole problem.

Comment: Thanks! in my case a new class was produced by class wizard producing this issue. Adding these headers as suggested fixed the issue, so I guess I may need to file a bug for visual studio 2019. tried over only need 2nd include...